# TypeError: setCart is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

The setCart is not working in this following code
I have passed cart,setcart as a prop to this function cart is accessable but setcart is not working.

```
export default function Cart({ cart, setCart }) {
  const deletecart = () => {
    console.log("delete");

    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container main">
        <h4>Items In Cart</h4>
      </div>
      <h3>Your Cart Items</h3>
      <button onClick={deletecart} className="btn btn-primary">
        Delete Cart
      </button>
      <button>Place Your Order</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is missing a closing a div. Apart from that it looks OK, so please provide the code that calls the Cart function. It is probably not passing in setCart correctly. I suggest using a linter to check your code. It would pick up the missing </div> for starters.

Comment: Here It is ~~~<Cart cart={cart} setcart={setCart}></Cart>

Comment: just before the `return` statement, why don't you do `console.log(setCart)`? This will show if the function is coming as a prop here or not, if not check the destructuring part (`{ cart, setCart}`) and if everything is fine there, then check the part where you do `<Cart cart={cart}.... />` and so on... This will help debug easily.

Answer (score 1):

`<Cart cart={cart} setcart={setCart}></Cart>`

should be

`<Cart cart={cart} setCart={setCart}></Cart>`

(That's a doh!) By the way, this type of thing would be picked up by TypeScript, and is why most React devs use it instead of raw JS.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark as answer/upvote.